# NGINX Config always load to default dir /usr/share/nginx/html

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vbulletin

I want to install vBulletin using NGINX but I don't know what wrong with my config, it's always load default dir at `/usr/share/nginx/html` instead of my config, before this I can't load installation file at `forum.fura.tech/core/install/install.php`.

I don't know why. I'm using `digitalocean` and `cloudflare`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name forum.fura.tech;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name forum.fura.tech;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/html/;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/forum.fura.tech.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/forum.fura.tech.error;
    server_tokens off;

    # strengthen ssl security
    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/private.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_body_buffer_size  1k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 100k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    sendfile on;

    rewrite /css.php$ /core/css.php  last;
    rewrite /install$ /core/install/ last;

    location ~* ^.+\.(js|json|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|pdf|png|css|woff|ttf|otf|eot)$ {
        root /var/www/html/forum.fura.tech;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found   off;
        expires 7d;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @vbulletin;
    }

    location = /admincp/ {
        try_files $uri @vbulletin;
    }

    location @vbulletin {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING    routestring=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @vbulletin;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```